# How to write to a file multiple times in C?

Tags: c, csv, io

I am writing a C file to that can output the performance time into a csv file. And I also want to write the results to the same csv file every time I run the executable. I'm using a trivial I/O format, and I'll pass in the same output file name with command line.

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    outFile = fopen(fileName,"w+");
    fprintf(outFile, "%d, %f\n",numbers,time_spent);
    fclose(outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I open the file, `fopen()` will delete the current content. Is there a way that I can open the file without delete the content?

Comment: `fopen(fileName, "a+");` This flag appends to the file,, check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0271c11d-4cf3-452b-af65-6c06473669fb/adding-row-into-existing-csv-file-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Use `fopen(fileName, "a+");` instead.